# Como implementar HMVC en codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hola estoy tratando de integrar mi CMS basado en codeigniter 2.1.0 usando este tutorial:
https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Pero, tengo un problema, estoy usando este código en mi aplicación en la ruta... `app\core\MY_Loader.php`:

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }
  public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) 
  {
    $nv = $view;
    $path = explode('/', $view);
    if($path[0] != 'default') {
      $file = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $view).'.php';
      if(! file_exists(VIEWPATH.$file)) { 
        $len = count($path); $i = 0;
        $path[0] = 'default';  $nv = '';
        foreach($path as $p) {
          if($i == $len - 1) {
            $nv .= $p;
          } else {
            $nv .= $p.'/';
          }
          $i++;
        }
      }
    }
    return $this->_ci_load(array(
      '_ci_view' => $nv, 
      '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars), 
      '_ci_return' => $return
    ));
  }
```

Y este es el código proporcionado por el tutorial en el archivo `MY_Loader.php`:

```
/* load the MX_Loader class */ 
require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Loader.php"; 
class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader {}
```

La verdad no sé como implementar HMVC para mi aplicación en este caso, Gracias por su ayuda!